# Accuracy of different time zone subtraction by using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, timezone

I finished my code to deal with different time zone subtraction but I got confused about the output.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from datetime import datetime
import time
import pytz
tw =  pytz.timezone('Asia/Taipei')
ola = pytz.timezone('US/Central')
olathe_dt = datetime.strptime('12/05/17 19:15:00', '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S').replace(tzinfo=ola)
tw_dt = datetime.now().replace(tzinfo=tw)
duration = tw_dt - olathe_dt
print('TW TIME: '+str(tw_dt))
print('OLA TIME: '+str(olathe_dt))
print('Duration: '+str(duration))
```

and the output is:

```
TW TIME: 2017-12-06 09:54:16.345347+08:06
OLA TIME: 2017-12-05 19:15:00-05:51
Duration: 0:42:16.345347
```

I think that timezone Asia/Taipei is +08:00 and US/Central is -06:00.
Why the output will be like this?

Comment: what do you expect the output to be like? The function is behaving exactly as expected

Comment: Use `localize`, not `replace`.  See the pytz docs.